# how to extract date from a datetime field inside a filter in django

Tags: django-views

I have used this query in my view..

```
temp2=transaction.objects.filter(user_id=client_obj,Date_of_trans.date()=rec_var1)[0].Trans_Amount
```

I need to compare a datetime field present in my model named Date_of_trans to a variable received from user but the code is not working... what query should be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a **sql query**. So you should think like that. How can you do this in sql. I mean **what condition will you apply in sql**. For finding records of particular date with datetime field you should **check records between start of the day to end of the day**.

try this

```
from datetime import datetime, time
temp2=transaction.objects.filter(user_id=client_obj,Date_of_trans>datetime.combine(rec_var1, time(0,0,0)), Date_of_trans <= datetime.combine(rec_var1, time(23,59,59)) )[0].Trans_Amount
```

The above code is written taking into consideration that **rec_var1 is a date()** object.

Here you check all transactions between start of the day, till end of the day. I think this will resolve your problem.

I've use datetime.combine function which combines date and time object to form datetime object which is required here.

Thanks

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation... :(

Comment: :D, then can you accept the answer. It will increase your reputation, :P